# join only a column of a table with another table

Tags: mysql, sql

i've the following query the gives me what i wan't (see table_entrees)

```
SELECT designation, ref1, ref2, ref3, sum( a.qte ) AS TotalQte
FROM table_entrees a
WHERE a.ref1 = 'VT2'
GROUP BY a.designation, a.ref1, a.ref2, a.ref3
```

table_entrees:

```
designation   ref1    ref2    ref3    TotalQte  
VT            VT2     GRIS    L       150
VT            VT2     GRIS    XL      150
VT            VT2     Jaune   L       150
VT            VT2     Jaune   XL      150
```

and another query the same as the first one but for another table

```
SELECT designation, ref1, ref2, ref3, sum( b.qte ) AS TotalQte2
FROM table_sorties b
WHERE a.ref1 = 'VT2'
GROUP BY b.designation, b.ref1, b.ref2, b.ref3
```

table_sorties:

```
designation   ref1  ref2      ref3  TotalQte2   
VT            VT2   GRIS      L     62
VT            VT2   JAUNE     L     15
```

But the problem is that i've tried to combine between the two just like the table below where it checks if ref1,ref2,ref3 of table_sorties exists in table_entrees and then show it's result else show a 0 in TotalQte2

```
designation   ref1    ref2    ref3    TotalQte      TotalQte2
VT            VT2     GRIS    L       150           62
VT            VT2     GRIS    XL      150           0
VT            VT2     Jaune   L       150           15
VT            VT2     Jaune   XL      150           0
```

i've tried the following query but didn't give the expected result!!

```
SELECT 
  a.designation, 
  a.ref1, 
  a.ref2, 
  a.ref3, 
  sum( a.qte ) AS TotalQte,
  sum( b.qte ) AS TotalQte2
FROM FROM table_entrees a,table_sorties b
WHERE a.ref1 = 'VT2'
GROUP BY a.designation, a.ref1, a.ref2, a.ref3
```

Comment: Do you have an id column or a unique identifier that you can join the tables on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use each of your queries as a subquery, and use `left outer join`:

```
SELECT q1.designation, q1.ref1, q1.ref2, q1.ref3, q1.TotalQte,
       coalesce(q2.TotalQte2, 0) as TotalQte2
FROM (SELECT designation, ref1, ref2, ref3, sum( a.qte ) AS TotalQte
      FROM table_entrees a
      WHERE a.ref1 = 'VT2'
      GROUP BY a.designation, a.ref1, a.ref2, a.ref3
     ) q1 LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT designation, ref1, ref2, ref3, sum( b.qte ) AS TotalQte2
      FROM table_sorties b
      WHERE a.ref1 = 'VT2'
      GROUP BY b.designation, b.ref1, b.ref2, b.ref3
     ) q2
     on q1.designation = q2.designation and
        q1.ref1 = q2.ref1 and
        q1.ref2 = q2.ref2 and
        q1.ref3 = q2.ref3;
```

When you do the join before the aggregation, you get a Cartesian product of all combinations of the `qte` fields from both tables.  The `sum()` on the Cartesian product will not be correct, in general.

Comment: @0x58 . . . There was a typo in the `join` conditions.  It should work correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to do a left join on the three ref columns , as stated in the previous answer.

When you do A left join B, all columns in table A are preserved. If there is no corresponding entry in table B, it will be shown as null.